# Using Test Users with FB Connect

Tags: fbconnect, facebook-test-users

I use OAuth login on my site, and would like to use the Test User API to do testing. However, I've run into a problem where I can't actually log in with a test user account.

One of the requirements is that the user needs to reauthenticate when they log in (passing `auth_type=reauthenticate` to the OAuth endpoint), so just being logged into Facebook as the test user is not enough.

1. I create a new test users
2. I set the password of the test user
3. I log in using the Developer App and obtain their email address from the Facebook main site
4. I click on the Login button on my site, and the Facebook login form pops up
5. I enter the email address and password
6. I am sent back to the login form without an error message

Is this even possible? This sounds suspiciously like [Why can't I login to test Facebook user accounts from the Android native app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6585165/), but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Actually, this may be something else because I can't log in with my normal account either. WTF??